# Retracting a close vote?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Is there any way to retract a close vote? I know that you can get rid of downvotes (and upvotes, for that matter), if the post has been edited. In fact, I recently made a trivial edit (adding a comma in an appropriate place) just to remove a downvote I decided I had issued too hastily.

But it doesn't seem like there is any way to retract close votes. Is this right?

I ask because [this recent question on Nietzsche](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/7468/how-does-nietzsche-disprove-the-existence-of-god) was suggested to be closed due to lack of citation, and difficulty in finding any source for the quote even with extensive searching. It had turned out that the quote was indeed from Nietzsche, and I found the quote after bringing up the issue with a friend who had recently taught on Nietzsche. The original quote provided in the post seems to be from an uncommon translation, and so was difficult to locate (except on some anti-atheism websites, who all seemed to be using this same uncommon translation).

Now that the source has been found, however, my close vote is no longer appropriate--- hence the desire to retract. Obviously, if the 5th vote to close is submitted, we can simply issue a vote to reopen and hopefully quickly reopen it. But why not simply allow users to retract close votes, especially since the reopening rate for questions is rather low. Is this a feature that should be requested? Or, does this feature already exist, and I've simply been unsuccessful in locating it?

Comment: I just stumbled across this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/915/can-we-have-the-ability-to-rescind-a-close-vote-before-it-closes

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't exist as far as I know. Please do let me know if you think there's some action you think we might want to take in this particular case.

Just in passing, generally speaking feature requests for the platform itself really belong on meta.SO by the way -- where core functional things about the system itself are being discussed and evaluated every day.

Comment: Ah ok, good to know about feature requests. I don't think there is anything we need to do here. Interestingly, the number of close votes dropped to 3 from 4, so maybe someone found a way to retract?

Comment: Either that, or a relatively veteran user deleted their account.

Answer (score 2):

Click again on "close". The box for "Why should this question be closed?" will appear. Bottom right is a button: "Retract Close Vote" (where the button: "Vote To Close", were before you clicked so hastily:)